# Google image search by image uploader form style

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to implement an image upload tool on my website, similar to how Google has done their image upload search. This would need to be able to have images dropped into it; have urls pasted into it; or have a user upload it from their own computer.

Another related question, how does Google have the selection method change when you click 'Paste URL' or 'Upload file'?

images.google.com for idea source.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Google spent several years developing the algorithms behind searching for images with other images, so if this a website you are developing for yourself, I'd explore other options. Otherwise, tell your boss it's impractical.

As for the method change, I imagine (without looking too closely) that they overlay the camera icon on the input, and on click, displays a `<div>` or other container element over the input field, which can then contain alternative input methods.

When the user clicks on Paste or Upload, it replaces the content of a sub container with the relevant HTML using jQuery or whichever JavaScript library it is that they use.

Comment: Ahh, my apologies, I haven't explained it properly. I'm just using their upload interface, not for the reason they use it, just to have users upload to my site.

Sorry about that!

Thanks for the explanation for the switch though.